# QSqlTableModel::setFilter and Sql Injection

Tags: qt, sql-injection, qsqltablemodel

I was wondering if there is a way to prevent SQL injection while using **QSqlTableModel::setFilter** and **no validation for WHERE clause Condition**.

I don't want to use QSqlQueryModel since I need edit functionality.

Answer (score 0):

you can set it like this:

```
QString filter = "Condition here";

if(filter.contains("drop") || filter.contains("delete") || filter.contains("insert"))
return; /*Stop here*/
```

I use it and works perfectly